# How to pause code for animation?

Tags: ios, google-maps, animation, swift, screenshot

I'm writing an app that uses a map to follow a user and trace the path taken. At the end of the session the user presses a button upon which the map zooms out to show the whole path and captures a screenshot of the map for later use. At the moment my app sends the animation command and then moves on to take the screenshot before the animation has a chance to pan out. How can I mitigate this without using a delay?

The code that initiates the animation followed by the code that captures the screen is as follows:

```
var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudes[0], longditudes[0]), coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudes[(latitudes.count)-1], longditudes[(longditudes.count)-1]))
var camera = mapView.cameraForBounds(bounds, insets:UIEdgeInsetsZero)
mapView.animateToCameraPosition(camera)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.frame.size)
mapView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [GMSMapViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p) to handle the callback. One way to do this would be to have the class implement the GMSMapViewDelegate protocol, and move the screenshot code to `-(void) mapView:idleAtCameraPosition:`

```
func initiateAnimation() {
  var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds( ... )
  var camera = mapView.cameraForBounds(bounds, insets:UIEdgeInsetsZero)
  mapView.delegate = self
  mapView.animateToCameraPosition(camera)
}

func mapView(view: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.frame.size)
  mapView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
  let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing that function to my attention, I'm going to go and have a good look at the rest of GMSMapViewDelegate. Thanks for the help!